# the xsd code does not validate a single element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need the ISBM to be unique and validate me on this page, https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

I have tried several ways, but although eclipse does not give me any faults, the validator does not accept the code

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Biblioteca
 xmlns="https://www.adrianfloresbecerra.com/biblioteca"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="www.adrianfloresbecerra.com/biblioteca.xsd">
  <Libro>
  <ISBN>000-000-000-000-1</ISBN>


  </Biblioteca>

 XSD:

<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="https://www.adrianfloresbecerra.com/biblioteca"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<element name="Biblioteca">
    <complexType>

                        <element name="ISBN">
                            <simpleType >
                                <restriction base="string">                                 
                                    <pattern                                        
                                        value="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9] 
         {3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{1}">
                                    </pattern>
                                </restriction>                                  
                            </simpleType>

                        </element>


                        </element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instance document has a start tag for a Libro element, with no end tag, so it's not well-formed, let alone being valid against the schema.

Comment: I have deleted most of the code, because if not, it would not let me upload it, but all the labels are well closed, the only thing that is not unique to the ISBN element